# How to understand SAN stores data at the block level, while NAS accesses data as files?

Tags: nas, storage, san

I am reading this document[SAN vs NAS](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3256312/what-is-a-san-and-how-does-it-differ-from-nas.html)

> A SAN stores data at the block level, while NAS accesses data as files. To a client OS, a SAN typically appears as a disk and exists as its own separate network of storage devices, while NAS appears as a file server.

I have several questions:

1.SAN stores data at the block level, while NAS accesses data as files.

how to understand this sentence? please give an example.

2.SAN typically appears as a disk, while NAS appears as a file server.

how to understand it?

is it means I can request a virtual disk from SAN, then use a partition formatting tool to format it like `ext4`?

and the file server is a virtual disk which has formatted already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAN**

A SAN disk is provisioned to a (PC/Server) system like an (external) hard disk that is accessed over a (Storage Area) Network, which could be Ethernet (using the iSCSI protocol), Fibre Channel (which is a separate, very low-latency and storage optimized networking technology) or SAS (Serial Attached SCSI). The main difference between SAN and NAS is that a SAN provisioned disk behaves like a local disk and can be accessed as block storage.

The SAN often provides "virtual" disks, carved from larger storage units inside the SAN Storage System, to multiple connected systems, usually in the form of a *LUN (Logical Unit) that can be mounted, partitioned and formatted by the target system with whatever tools or filesystems it supports*.

A SAN Storage system is optimized for performance, scalability and reliability and usually has large caches, two or more redundant controllers and very high internal and external bandwidth.

**NAS**

A NAS is a (dedicated) File Server, with is own internal disk partitioning, file system and redundancy. A NAS is accessed with File Sharing protocols and their associated access control and permissions, like NFS, SMB/CIFS and sometimes FTP or WebDAV.

High-end NASs can also have two or more redundant controllers, large amounts of cache memory and high internal and external bandwidth.

To make matters a bit more confusing, many NAS systems offer the option of providing iSCSI LUNs to clients, which technically makes them into a combined NAS and SAN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the client, the SAN will export whole virtual disks (with a protocol like iSCSI) and the client OS has to mount it with its own filesystem logic. There should be no restrictions on the supported logics (`ext4`, swap, others).

A NAS will be seen as a shared directory, and file accesses are just transmitted with one of the supported protocol (CIFS, NFS). The file system logic runs in the NAS.